# Angular UI Select Options issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am trying to use angular UI select and I am running into problems. When my form loads up the options seem to be populating correctly but it doesn't have a value selected from my model. For example the screenshot below shows an item that has priority (2) Normal selected but as you can see it appears to be empty when the form loads.

[image]

Then if I select one of the options and save it trys to use the entire object

```
{"text":"(2) Normal","value":"(2) Normal"}
```

instead of just the value but still the top portion appears empty.

```
<ui-select ng-model="currentItem.PriorityValue" theme="bootstrap" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a priority">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.currentItem.PriorityValue}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="option in (data.priority.options |  filter: $select.search) track by option.value">
        <span ng-bind="option.text"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

EDIT: In case it helps this is what I was doing that worked before but now I need the filtering functionality of the select

```
<select class="form-control modal-input" id="PriorityValueInput" data-ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in data.priority.options" data-ng-model="currentItem.PriorityValue"></select>
```

Comment: In your repeat try `option.value as option in (data.priority.options |  filter: $select.search) track by option.value`

Comment: Thanks George this has helped. The data is now correctly saving to the server as just (2) Normal however, the select box still just shows empty instead of showing the currently selected option.

Comment: I managed to fix this by changing "<ui-select-match>{{$select.currentItem.PriorityValue}}</ui-select-match>" to "<ui-select-match>{{currentItem.PriorityValue}}</ui-select-match>". Now I have another problem though. When you type you filter and then delete what you typed the currently selected option disappears. Is there an option to make it not remove options from the dropdown even if they are already selected?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the same in the below plunker . hope this will help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BQuiDDULwVJgRRzlRx4x?p=preview

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a country">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select ">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="country in ctrl.countries | filter: $select.search">
  <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

and in controller to select an option on page load

```
me.country.selected = {"name":"Albania","code":"AL"};
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I am looking for. In your example your ctrl.country.selected contains the entire object {"name":"Albania","code":"AL"}. This is what I am trying to avoid. My currentItem.PriorityValue contains just the string "(2) Normal"

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem as yours so i wanna share my solution as well, so i assume this is your data structure is the **lst**. I understand that you only store or get the value from your database, so i added filter to get the object from the ***lst*** base on the value ***(2) Normal*** and assign it to ***option.PriorityValue***

```
  var lst = [
    {"text":"(1) High","value":"(1) High"}, 
    {"text":"(2) Normal","value":"(2) Normal"}, 
    {"text":"(3) Low","value":"(3) Low"} 
  ];
  $scope.data = {
      priority: {
        options: lst
      }
  };
  //You can change the value '(2) Normal'
  var newTemp = $filter("filter")(lst, {"value":'(2) Normal'});
  $scope.option = {
     PriorityValue: newTemp[0]
  }
```

And here is the markup, if you want to get just the value when the dropdown is selected use option.PriorityValue.value

```
  <ui-select ng-model="option.PriorityValue" theme="selectize" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a priority">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select priority in the list...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="option in (data.priority.options |  filter: $select.search) track by option.value">
          <span ng-bind-html="option.text | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          <small ng-bind-html="option.value | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Here is what i have done for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IIjSaHOHgzE9l2JV3b1Q?p=preview

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this also doesn't really cover what I am looking for though. your are binding your ng-model to option.PriorityValue which you are setting to the entire object {"value":'(2) Normal'}. I don't want the object I just want the string "(2) Normal".

Comment: Beyond that I have this working as intended now with one problem. When the form loads (2) Normal is selected as it should be. Then when I click to open the dropdown all three options are listed as they should be. Then I type to filter and the irrelevant ones dissapear but when I backspace and delete what I typed only the two currently unselected options return in the dropdown. How do I make it stop filtering out the currently selected option? When no text is typed in I want all options to show, even the one currently selected.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of angular-ui-select? i think what you wanted to happen may not available on angular-ui-select plugin, i did look around stackoverflow and read the documentations, the return will always be an object and to match the selected value it should also be an object structure the same in the list, that is why i used $filter to create that workaround.

Comment: So i tried the filtering, i entered some text, did the backspace until everything is cleared and it displayed all the options completely, i don't think it filters out the currently selected one, can you check again? what is your filter string? you can duplicate the plunker i made and try to play with it.

Comment: Ya I don't know what is going on either. I essentially duplicated my code in the plunkr below but everything works right there, but for some reason in my actual solution as soon as you type to filter the currently selected option is removed from the dropdown
http://plnkr.co/edit/losvPD?p=preview

Comment: Have you checked your ui-select version? I hope you find my answers as useful.

Comment: Ya I am on the latest I think. 0.17.1